# MVC4 ReturnUrl is not getting set after changing LoginUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="https://Login.Url.I.Have.To.Use" name=".Name" protection="Validation" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
```

I have this entry in my Web.Config which works fine to direct the application to the desired loginUrl. The problem is that when I set the loginUrl here it no longer adds the returnUrl so after login it just stays on the loginUrl instead of going back to the requested page. Does anyone know why this would cause the returnUrl not to get set and how I can fix it?

If I don't set the loginUrl then it does add the returnUrl, but it tries to go to the default login.aspx which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't believe it took me 2 days to figure this out, but the problem was just that I had left

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

out of the web.config

Comment: I won't say how long it took me to figure this out =/